# is try_files processing context in named location different from normal location?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have the flow nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /mypath/p1/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @verify;
    }

    location @verify {
        root /mypath/p2/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

/mypath/p1/ directory contains the file index.html, but /mypath/p2/ not.
when i request a file which not exists in all the two directories, nginx return the /mypath/p1/index.html content.

If i modify @verify location to:

```
location @verify {
    root /mypath/p2/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

when i request a file which not exists in all the two directories, nginx return 404.

According to the nginx docs : [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) :

> the processing is performed in the current context. The path to a file is constructed from the file parameter according to the root and alias directives.

But, in the named location @verify, the result is that:

- if use =404, the result as the docs describes
- if not use =404, return index.html with parent context path

and i can not find any docs with the context change description.
Any one can help me to confirm the action?

Comment: nginx version: nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was my own stupidity.
If use =404, /index.html is treated as a file, so return 404
If not use =404, /index.html is treated as a URL(because it is the last one), it redirects to the https://my.domain.com/index.html, and then math the root location.